# No sound in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS - Intel NUC Tigerlake Laptop

Tags: sound

I only get "Dummy Output". Here is the hwinfo. Any tips??

```
18: PCI 1f.3: 0401 Multimedia audio controller                  
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: nS1_.KZr++YVh4W1
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1f.3
  Hardware Class: sound
  Device Name: "Onboard - Sound"
  Model: "Intel Multimedia audio controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0xa0c8 
  SubVendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  SubDevice: pci 0x2097 
  Revision: 0x20
  Driver: "sof-audio-pci"
  Driver Modules: "snd_sof_pci"
  Memory Range: 0x603e1e0000-0x603e1e3fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0x603e000000-0x603e0fffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 186 (1936 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000A0C8sv00008086sd00002097bc04sc01i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: snd_sof_pci is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_sof_pci"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

Comment: I plugged external Speakers into the headphone jack of my NUC. It worked.

Comment: I have the same trouble.... Did you solve it?